# Sum on same column with two different conditions mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named **Order** with schema as

```
user_id, state    amount
11       success  100
11       FAILED   10
11       FAILED   10
11       success  17
```

state can have two values (Success/Failed).

I want to fetch `sum(amount) when state = "SUCCESS" - sum(amount) when state = "FAILED"`
means difference total amount when success - total amount when failed.

I can solve this problem in 2 queries.

```
A = select id, sum(amount) when state = "SUCCESS"
B = select id, sum(amount) when state = "FAILED"
```

And solution will be **A-B**.
Is there any way I can achieve this in single sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use case when

```
    select user_id,sum(case when state = 'SUCCESS' then amount else 0 end)-sum(case when state = 'FAILED' then amount else 0 end)
from table group by user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when state = 'SUCCESS' then amount else - amount end) as total
from t
where state in ('SUCCESS', 'FAILED')
group by id;
```

I assume that you want this sum per `id` and not overall in the table.

Comment: Missing `end` for the case expression?

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when state = "SUCCESS" then amount else o end) -
    sum(case when state = "FAILED" then amount else o end)
    from tbl
group by userid
```